# How can set different height of header color on the first page of resume?

Tags: header-footer, customize

```
\documentclass[letter,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[bottom=0.8in,top=0.8in, left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\color{white}Resume}
\fancyhead[L]{\Large\color{white}Dmitry Yakovlev}



\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{}
\fancyfoot[l]{\thepage | Page}
\fancyfoot[r]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%%%%%%%%%%% pdflatex %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%% xelatex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
% \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{navyblue}{RGB}{0,54,123}
% line spacing
\linespread{1.0}

% section reformatting
%\titleformat{\section}{\color{black} \large}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}]
%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%\newcommand{\sectitle}[1]{
%    \vspace{1.5ex}
 %   \section{#1}
 %   \vspace{-3ex}
 %   \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.7pt}
  %  \vspace{-4ex}
%}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large}{}{0pt}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]




\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\color{navyblue}%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\rule[-20mm]{\paperwidth}{20mm}}%
}
\newmdenv[
  backgroundcolor=gray!5,
  skipabove=20pt,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
]{reminder}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\topskip=20pt
\parskip=10pt
%\parindent=0pt
%\baselineskip=15pt


\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor={linkcolour!90}, linkcolor={linkcolour!90}}
\begin{document}

\section{\color{navyblue} SUMMARY OF QUALIFICATIONS}
Results-driven, customer-focused, and innovative professional with years of work experience in diverse software development roles. Highly skilled in JavaScript, React, Node.js and associated technologies. Hands-on experience in front-end and back-end development of web-based applications and advanced development methodologies, as well as design and development of automation systems. My proven capabilities in self-management, get-up-and-go attitude, and ability to understand complex coding with ease make me an ideal candidate to fit the position of software engineer, and I am confident that I will be a valuable asset to your organisation.

\begin{reminder}

\begin{center}
    \underline{\color{navyblue}\Large Core Competencies/Areas of Expertise}
\end{center}

Software Engineering $•$ Front-end and Back-end Development $\bullet$ DevOps $\bullet$ CI/CD $\bullet$ Technical Support and Troubleshooting \\
Programming Skills $\bullet$ Analytical Skills $\bullet$ Project Management $\bullet$ Root-cause Analysis\\
Creativity $\bullet$ Attention to Details $\bullet$ Leadership and Teamwork Abilities $\bullet$ Decision Making $\bullet$ Critical Thinking $\bullet$ Effective Communication
\end{reminder}

\section{ \color{navyblue}TECHNICAL SKILLS PROFILE}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Please help me. I want a header as in this image on the first page only. The header of rest of the document is right for me as given in latex code

[image: x]

Comment: You shouldn't post the same question twice, improve your question you asked earlier today rather than re-asking it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` applied only to the first page (by using  `\thispagestyle{...}`) with another style.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[letter,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[bottom=0.8in,top=0.8in, left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{eso-pic}% here <<<<<<

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{firstfancy}{% ONLy to the first page
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\color{white}Resume}
\fancyhead[L]{\Large\color{white}Dmitry Yakovlev}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[l]{\thepage~|~Page}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\color{navyblue}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \AtPageUpperLeft{\rule[-20mm]{\paperwidth}{20mm}}}
}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\color{red}Resume}
\fancyhead[L]{\Large\color{red}Dmitry Yakovlev}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[l]{\thepage~|~Page}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{18.0pt} % needed <<<<


%%%%%%%%%%% pdflatex %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%% xelatex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
% \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{navyblue}{RGB}{0,54,123}
% line spacing
\linespread{1.0}

% section reformatting
%\titleformat{\section}{\color{black} \large}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}]
%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%\newcommand{\sectitle}[1]{
%    \vspace{1.5ex}
%   \section{#1}
%   \vspace{-3ex}
%   \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.7pt}
%  \vspace{-4ex}
%}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large}{}{0pt}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\newmdenv[
backgroundcolor=gray!5,
skipabove=20pt,
skipbelow=\topsep,
]{reminder}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\topskip=20pt
\parskip=10pt
%\parindent=0pt
%\baselineskip=15pt


\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor={linkcolour!90}, linkcolor={linkcolour!90}}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{firstfancy}% to be applied only to the first page
        
    \section{\color{navyblue} SUMMARY OF QUALIFICATIONS}
    Results-driven, customer-focused, and innovative professional with years of work experience in diverse software development roles. Highly skilled in JavaScript, React, Node.js and associated technologies. Hands-on experience in front-end and back-end development of web-based applications and advanced development methodologies, as well as design and development of automation systems. My proven capabilities in self-management, get-up-and-go attitude, and ability to understand complex coding with ease make me an ideal candidate to fit the position of software engineer, and I am confident that I will be a valuable asset to your organisation.
    
    \begin{reminder}
        
        \begin{center}
            \underline{\color{navyblue}\Large Core Competencies/Areas of Expertise}
        \end{center}
        
        Software Engineering $•$ Front-end and Back-end Development $\bullet$ DevOps $\bullet$ CI/CD $\bullet$ Technical Support and Troubleshooting \\
        Programming Skills $\bullet$ Analytical Skills $\bullet$ Project Management $\bullet$ Root-cause Analysis\\
        Creativity $\bullet$ Attention to Details $\bullet$ Leadership and Teamwork Abilities $\bullet$ Decision Making $\bullet$ Critical Thinking $\bullet$ Effective Communication
    \end{reminder}
    
    \section{ \color{navyblue}TECHNICAL SKILLS PROFILE}
    
    \lipsum[1-10]
    
\end{document}
```